# MongoDb Bulkwrite does not seem to throw any Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been trying to execute a Bulkwrite query in Mongoose, and I don't know for what reasons It doesn't throw error

```
let input = [
    {
        "variantId": "5e1760fbdfaf28038242d676",
        "quantity": 5

    },
    {
        "variantId": "5e17e67b73a34d53160c7252",
        "quantity": 13
    }
]

try{
let bulkArr = [];

for (const i of input) {
    bulkArr.push({
        updateOne: {
            "filter": { "_id": Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(i.variantId) },
            "update": { $inc: { "stocks": - i.quantity } }
        }
    })
}

await Variant.bulkWrite(bulkArr)
}
catch(e){
   console.log(e);
}
```

I have tried to update values not present in the database,
as well as I have tried to update stocks to negative values which is explicitly set to min:0
both of the following query should have thrown an error. But no error was thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating non-existing document is not considered as write error. You can `console.log` the result to see that it simply informs you about the number of matched elements:

```
let result = await Test.bulkWrite(bulkArr);
console.log(result);
```

which prints:

```
...
nMatched: 0,
...
```

Running `$inc` with a negative value is still valid - you can do that and even if you have a validation rule like `min:0` it will not be applied since `$inc` gets executed on database server and mongoose doesn't know if your field's value will get negative after this operation or not. The `min` rule will be applied when you want to insert a new document or replace existing one using `.save()` method.

How to get an error then ? Try to violate unique key by inserting the same value into unique index - that situation throws an exception explicitly.